# *ngFor goes out of order after navigating to page through this.router.navigate(); in ts file

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, frontend, ngfor

I've got a main page of movies that I want to display in a specific order based on the array given to the ngFor, but whenever I use a routerlink that's in a ts file to navigate to that component it displays the data at random. I've even tried using bootstraps order- css and it is not displaying in order.

```
<div
*ngFor="let film of filmIterables; index as i"
[class]="'col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 card-align order-' + i">

<div [class]="'card img-fade'">
  <a [routerLink]="['/home/films', film]">
    <img
      [src]="'../../assets/img/posters/' + film + '.jpg'"
      alt="film"
      [class]="'img-fluid'"
    />
  </a>
</div>
```

I would love a solution for this, I want to learn how to build with rendered components like this without this error in the future. The routerLink goes from /auth/login to /home/films and it doesn't retain the original order of when the component was first loaded.

Here's what the app looks like if you're curious:
[studio ghibli portfolio project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f2Dhw.jpg)

and here's after I navigate through this.router.navigate in a different component's typescript file: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1KfKU.jpg)

Okay This is fascinating, I found the error was using a variable reference to the image name with local images files. The variable 'filmIterables'
was a direct reference to this file, which is now just to the links:

```
export const FilmUrls: any[] = ['Spirited Away','My Neighbor Totoro','Laputa Castle in the Sky','Princess Mononoke','Nausicaa of the Valley of the Wind','Arrietty','Grave of the Fireflies',"Howl's Moving Castle","Kiki's Delivery Service",'My Neighbors the Yamadas','Ocean Waves','Only Yesterday','Pom Poko','Ponyo','Porco Rosso','Tales From Earthsea','From Up On Poppy Hill','The Cat Returns','The Tale of Princess Kaguya','The Wind Rises','When Marnie Was There','Whisper of the Heart',];

export const FilmLinks: any[] = ['https://www.studioghibli.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/1055-title-treatment-portrait-key-art-normal-medium-683x1024.jpg','https://www.studioghibli.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/poster_mononoke-683x1024.jpg','https://www.studioghibli.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/poster_my_neighbor_totoro-683x1024.jpg','https://www.studioghibli.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/1100-title-treatment-portrait-key-art-normal-medium-683x1024.jpg','https://www.studioghibli.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/14815-title-treatment-portrait-key-art-normal-medium-683x1024.jpg','https://www.studioghibli.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/2783-title-treatment-portrait-key-art-normal-medium-683x1024.jpg','https://www.studioghibli.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/1476-title-treatment-portrait-key-art-normal-medium-683x1024.jpg','https://www.studioghibli.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/poster_porco_rosso-683x1024.jpg','https://www.studioghibli.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/1475-title-treatment-portrait-key-art-normal-medium-683x1024.jpg','https://www.studioghibli.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/18651-title-treatment-portrait-key-art-normal-medium-683x1024.jpg','https://www.studioghibli.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/18474-title-treatment-portrait-key-art-normal-medium-683x1024.jpg','https://www.studioghibli.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/1484-title-treatment-portrait-key-art-normal-medium-683x1024.jpg','https://www.studioghibli.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/poster_kiki-683x1024.jpg','https://www.studioghibli.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/1483-title-treatment-portrait-key-art-normal-medium-683x1024.jpg','https://www.studioghibli.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/22719-title-treatment-portrait-key-art-normal-medium-683x1024.jpg','https://www.studioghibli.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/poster_wind_rises-683x1024.jpg','https://www.studioghibli.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/poster_cat_returns-683x1024.jpg','https://www.studioghibli.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/15673-title-treatment-portrait-key-art-normal-medium-683x1024.jpg','https://www.studioghibli.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/5845-title-treatment-portrait-key-art-normal-medium-683x1024.jpg','https://www.studioghibli.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/1482-title-treatment-portrait-key-art-normal-medium-683x1024.jpg','https://www.studioghibli.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/1479-title-treatment-portrait-key-art-normal-medium-683x1024.jpg','https://www.studioghibli.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/16933-title-treatment-portrait-key-art-normal-medium-683x1024.jpg','https://www.studioghibli.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/arrietty_poster-683x1024.jpg','https://www.studioghibli.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/Isao-Takahata-and-His-Tale-of-the-Princess-Kaguya-683x1024.jpg',];
```

That's kind of wild, this is a random error dealing with local file references, it ignores the order when I'm referencing the local file names by string, but it may work if I have the array reference the link to an exact image instead.

Here's a stackblitz version of the project: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-fyqmhc

Comment: can you reproduce this issue in stackblitz.com?

Comment: A stackblitz would indeed be good. But also - how are you building up filmIterables? It will take that ordering..

Comment: Hey thanks for the feedback guys I found something interesting. I had to go from local images to links to each of the images that I pulled in through an array in a typescript file. I originally had the folder names as string in there so I could also use it as the links in the nav, if you click on 'Films' in the navbar you'll see what I mean. Now I'm not getting an error when I go from 'Users' then click login and go back to landing. It's kinda wild, I'll try adding that into my local project.

Comment: I reproduced this in Stackblitz but it doesn't lose order in Stackblitz. Any idea of what could cause this or how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

in my opinion you should always do a javascript sort of your data in whatever .ts file accompanies your *ngFor loop. (filmIterables in your case). you should never assume the data is already sorted.

and don't use `order-' + i`

Comment: The ts is ordered correctly, the links correspond to the images just fine, and upon initial render all of those are placed on the screen according to the order of the ts file. When I go from Users routerlink to login I'll go back and all of those are out of order. They link together fine, and I have no fix to that issue, I just tried putting order in their to see if the css would fix it, and it didn't when I rerendered, and won't scale with random amounts of incoming data.

Comment: I guess I don't understand what the problem is. Why don't you simply resort them as part of your ngOnInit method? That way every time you visit the route they are sorted properly?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to follow the order based on the array given, please replace
'index as i' in

`<div *ngFor="let film of filmIterables; index as i" [class]="'col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 card-align order-' + i">`

By default, the comparator will be by Unicode point value, and therefore it looks weird.

You can get your specific order based on your array given if you do like it above.
Thanks for your researchable question.

Comment: I appreciate the clear answer and blunt approach, but this did not solve my issue in my local project, but it did in stackblitz along with the rest of the answers. I don't really understand why routerlink is rearranging the ngFor components that have already been initialized, but it is and I still don't have a fix for it. I've already completed everything else for this project, if you would like to replicate this yourself and find a way to fix it I'd give you a hug. Here's the link: https://github.com/roninMo/Studio-Ghibli-Site-Client

Comment: Everything's already put together and neat, it's pretty fancy too! I've built this for my portfolio, and I'd love to learn a fix for something important like this. Just check out the landing page man